# How to disable Dnsmasq listening on port 53 on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: dnsmasq

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

`airgeddon` has it:

```
The port 53/udp is being used by some program or process different than airgeddon (probably dnsmasq).
```

How to disable Dnsmasq listening on port 53?

Output of `sudo lsof -i :53`:

```
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
dnsmasq 2538  lxd    8u  IPv4  43618      0t0  UDP 10.129.138.1:domain 
dnsmasq 2538  lxd    9u  IPv4  43619      0t0  TCP 10.129.138.1:domain (LISTEN)
dnsmasq 2538  lxd   10u  IPv6  43620      0t0  UDP [fd42:715f:2ebc:cc33::1]:domain 
dnsmasq 2538  lxd   11u  IPv6  43621      0t0  TCP [fd42:715f:2ebc:cc33::1]:domain (LISTEN)
```

Output of `systemctl is-active dnsmasq`

```
inactive
```

Output of `netstat -tulnp | grep 53`

```
tcp        0      0 10.129.138.1:53         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2538/dnsmasq        
tcp6       0      0 fd42:715f:2ebc:cc33::53 :::*                    LISTEN      2538/dnsmasq        
udp        0      0 10.129.138.1:53         0.0.0.0:*                           2538/dnsmasq        
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:67              0.0.0.0:*                           2538/dnsmasq        
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53433           0.0.0.0:*                           964/avahi-daemon: r 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           964/avahi-daemon: r 
udp6       0      0 fd42:715f:2ebc:cc33::53 :::*                                2538/dnsmasq        
udp6       0      0 :::547                  :::*                                2538/dnsmasq        
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                964/avahi-daemon: r
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**fuser** command will do the job:

fuser -n udp -k 53

Comment: You could improve your answer by explaini g how it works

Comment: and add some code formating